# How to show that absolute value of a complex number is invariant under complex conjugation?

Tags: complex-numbers

How to show that absolute value of a complex number is invariant under complex conjugation?

my solution: Counterexample.
$f(abs(1-i))= \overline{abs(1-i)}=\overline{1+i}=1-i \neq abs(1-i)$? 
is there something I am missing?

Comment: $abs(1-i)=\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{2}\neq 1+i$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of absolute value of a complex number? Because then the invariance under conjugation follows almost immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=|a-bi|$

$|z|=\sqrt{z\cdot\overline{z}}=\sqrt{\overline{z}\cdot z}=|\overline{z}|$

Comment: So is absolute value of a complex number same as modulus?

Comment: Well, that's the definition I know of and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Absolute_value_and_argument) gives the same definition.

Comment: @alvoutila: The absolute value, modulus or length of a complex number is different words for the same operation.

Answer (score 0):

You write $$f(abs(1-i))= \overline{abs(1-i)}=\overline{1+i}=1-i \neq abs(1-i)$$
your notation is strange you should write $$f(|1-i|)= \overline{|1-i|}=\overline{|1+i|}\neq1-i \neq |1-i|$$ you must know that $|a+bi|$ or absolute value of complex number is real number you miss that?